# How to nest hide() in a toggle() jQuery?

Tags: jquery, nested, toggle, hide

I tried to add hide() option to a div that has already had a toggle(). so that when div is expanded, the text is long enough, at the end of the text I want to have an anchor, when clicked the div to be hidden. I tried as below, but it did not work. For the time being site is working nice, but I would like to add this feature.
The HTML is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h5').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
    $(this).parent().next().next().next().toggle();
  });
  $('h5').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('div.description').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  <h1>14-nov-2019</h1>
  <h2>What is Urespray?</h2>
  <h5>click for more</h5>
</div>
<div class="description">
  <p>text text long text</p>
  <h5>Less</h5>
</div>
```

The site with this is below,  look for section 'Articole tehnice', press where is written 'click pentru articol'. Thx
    http://agroline.eu/articole-tehnice.html#info-articole

Answer (score 0):

You could create new element for toggle that will also change its text based on visibility of the description element. This solution will also work if you have multiple same elements [`demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/nr4saexv/)

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  const desc = $(this).prev('.description');
  desc.toggle();
  $(this).text(desc.is(':visible') ? 'Show less' : "Show more")
})
```

```css
.description {
  display: none;
}

.toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  <h1>14-nov-2019</h1>
  <h2>What is Urespray?</h2>
</div>
<div class="description">
  <p>text text long text</p>
</div>
<h5 class="toggle">Show more</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nenad Vracar answer is good.
Another way according your question, you may try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.taggle_description').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().next().toggle();
      });
      $('.hide_this_div').click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
      });
    });

.description {
      display: none;
    }

<div class="title">
  <h1>14-nov-2019</h1>
  <h2>What is Urespray?</h2>
  <h5 class="taggle_description">click for more</h5>
</div>
<div class="description">
  <p>text text long text</p>
  <h5 class="hide_this_div">Less</h5>
</div>
```